# When I add new record to the Entity,it gives DbUpdateException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

// Here is the controller that reads a file uploaded.It works successfully when file is uploaded to App_Data,but when uploaded to MS SQL Server it gives error as "Invalid Object dbo.Prescription"

```
using SastiDawaai.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;

namespace SastiDawaai.Controllers
{
public class MedicineController : Controller
{

    // GET: Medicine
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MedicineContext medctx = null;
        using(medctx=new MedicineContext())
        {
        List<Medicine> medicinelist=medctx.Medicines.ToList();
        return View(medicinelist);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        MedicineContext medctx = null;
        Prescription pres = null;
        if(file!=null && file.ContentLength>0)
        {
            ////upolading files to App_Server
            var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), filename);
            file.SaveAs(path);

            //uploading Files to database
            var file_content=new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
            var content=file_content.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);

                using (medctx = new MedicineContext())
                {
                    pres = new Prescription
                    {
                        Prescription_Receipt = content,
                        File_Name = filename,
                        Submitted_Date = DateTime.Now,


                    };


                    medctx.Prescriptions.Add(pres);
                    medctx.SaveChanges();

                }



        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }






}
```

}

//Here is the Model for Prescription

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SastiDawaai.Models
{

public class Prescription
{
    [Key]
    public int Prescription_Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Prescription_Receipt { get; set; }
    public DateTime Submitted_Date { get; set; }
    public string File_Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

//here is the DBContext Class having 2 DBSets "Medicine" and "Prescription"
//There is no issue in getting records and inserting Records in Medicine entity,the issue only occurs when adding record to any additional DBSet added to the context.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SastiDawaai.Models
{
public class MedicineContext:DbContext
{

    public virtual DbSet<Medicine> Medicines { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Prescription> Prescriptions { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you Table name in your database

you entity is Prescription and your table name should be PrescriptionS,and also check you table schema, in your Entity it's Dbo so your table in your database should be the same schema.

Comment: Table Name is "Prescription"

Comment: Table Name is "dbo.Prescription" in my db which i feel is right with model name "Prescription".

Comment: so rename you table to Prescriptions Or add Table Attribute in your model to.
by default EF use plural name for mapping.

Comment: when table name is changed to Prescriptions,it gives other error saying "Invalid Column Name "Prescription_Id"

Comment: in your model you have Prescription_Id, but in your database you don't have

Comment: also if you use database first, i prefer to use EF Power tools to create my class

Comment: Thanks dude,it was my stupidity that I had Prescription_Id Spelled wrong in db.